# Dplyr workflow reflecting Mean Square Error estimator in change point analysis

Tags: r, time-series, dplyr, panel-data, mean-square-error

## Background

Hi, I would like to check whether the provided [**`dplyr`**](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) workflow reflects the calculation of *Mean Square Error estimator* as descried by [*Taylor (2010)*](http://www.variation.com/cpa/tech/changepoint.html).

### Problem

I would like for the workflow to reflect the following equation:
[image: equation]

where:

- **24** reflects the total number of observation in Taylor's data set. In the case of the provided data this would correspond to **10** observations per group.

### Data

The utilised data is fairly straightforward and resembles the extract:

```
set.seed(123)
dta <- data.frame(group = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 10),
                  year = rep(2001:2010, 3),
                  value = round(runif(30),2))
```

### Suggested workflow

The draft workflow would correspond to the code:

```
# Pkgs
Vectorize(require)(package = c("dplyr", "magrittr"),
                               char = TRUE)

# Workflow
dta %<>%
  arrange(group, year) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(X1 = cumsum(value) / row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(X2 = cumsum(lead(value)) / (length(value) - row_number())) %>% 
  mutate(MSEe = cumsum((value - X1) ^ 2  + (value - X2) ^ 2))
```

---

## Reference

*Taylor, 2010, Change-point analysis: a powerful new tool for detecting changes* Available: http://www.variation.com/cpa/tech/changepoint.html

Comment: Hi Konrad, it appears to be missing m? And if I am not wrong, you need to split into upper m group and lower m group

Comment: @chinsoon12 Thanks for showing the interest. Sorry, I should have explain in a greater detail in his original example Taylor uses monthly data so the the *m* value corresponds to each month. In the case of the provided data, which is annual, *m* would reflect each year. As the data is ordered by year within each group I was thinking of using `row_number()` call to refer to a current row. In terms of the split, I was hoping for the workflow to split the data at each row and return *MSE(m)* to find the smallest value, hence the `cumsum()` calls.

Comment: mse <- function(x, m) {
    meanX1 <- sum(x[1:m]) / m
    meanX2 <- sum(x[(m+1):length(x)]) / (length(x)-m)
    sum((x[1:m] - meanX1)^2) + sum((x[(m+1):length(x)] - meanX2)^2)
} #mse
mse(dta$value[dta$group=="A"], 1)

i did a non-plyr implementation and found differences in the results vs your implementation. but i do not quite know how to fix it using dplyr as the issue is having to net a column by an element in a diff column each time.

Comment: @chinsoon12 Thanks very much for your contribution. If you wish, please feel free to suggest it as an answer, it may be that no one will comment on the `dplyr` aspect of the code.

Comment: it doesnt really answer your qn so i would rather not post it as an answer.

Comment: @chinsoon12 Sure, no problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have so far ... hope to learn a better way

```
dta %>%
    arrange(group, year) %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate(cmX1=cummean(value), cmX2=(sum(value)-cumsum(value)) / (length(value) - row_number())) %>%
    do(data.frame(m=1:nrow(.), 
        MSE=sapply(1:nrow(.), function(n) sum((.$value[1:n] - .$cmX1[n])^2) + 
                sum((.$value[(n+1):length(.$value)] - .$cmX2[n])^2)))) %>% 
    ungroup()
```

numerical check:

```
mse <- function(x, m) { 
    meanX1 <- sum(x[1:m]) / m 
    meanX2 <- sum(x[(m+1):length(x)]) / (length(x)-m) 
    sum((x[1:m] - meanX1)^2) + sum((x[(m+1):length(x)] - meanX2)^2) 
} #mse 

dta <- dta[order(dta$group, dta$year),]
sapply(1:10, function(n) mse(dta$value[dta$group=="A"], n))
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it's a start. I was also thinking of embedding a function in [`RcppRoll`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RcppRoll). Ideally, I was thinking that the question would boil down to making use of the [window functions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html) in `dplyr`.